# Importing an item makes my spider unfindable?

Tags: scrapy

My problem is that a spider seems not to be found by the scrapy framework for some reason. I got this spider :

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from propreties.items import htmltableitem


class SymbolspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "symbolspider"

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range(0,10):
            yield Request( 'https://www.google.com/finance?q=%27&restype=company&noIL=1&num=50&ei=VPBjWJHKK9S7U6_dmvgM&start='+str(i) )

    def parse(self, response):
        l=ItemLoader(item=htmltableitem(), response=response)
        l.add_xpath('htmltable', ".//*[@id='gf-viewc']/div/div[2]/form/table/tbody/child::*")
        return l.load_item()
```

When I run `scrapy crawl symbolspider -o output.csv` it errors with :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 142, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 88, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 149, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 57, in run
    self.crawler_process.crawl(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 162, in crawl
    crawler = self.create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 190, in create_crawler
    return self._create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 194, in _create_crawler
    spidercls = self.spider_loader.load(spidercls)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 51, in load
    raise KeyError("Spider not found: {}".format(spider_name))
KeyError: 'Spider not found: symbolspider'
```

Funny thing is when I remove the line `from propreties.items import htmltableitem` it now detects the spider but just yields an error due to the fact that the items calls are unknown. What is happening ?

Edit : `scrapy list` returns

```
/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py:37: RuntimeWarning: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 31, in _load_all_spiders
    for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 71, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/volt/projects/scrapy/googlefinance/googlefinance/spiders/symbolspider.py", line 4, in <module>
    from propreties.items import htmltableitem
ImportError: No module named 'propreties'
Could not load spiders from module 'googlefinance.spiders'. Check SPIDER_MODULES setting
  warnings.warn(msg, RuntimeWarning)
```

And `tree` :

```
├── googlefinance
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── items.py
│   ├── middlewares.py
│   ├── pipelines.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   └── settings.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   └── spiders
│       ├── dataspider.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __pycache__
│       │   ├── dataspider.cpython-35.pyc
│       │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│       │   └── symbolspider.cpython-35.pyc
│       └── symbolspider.py
├── logs
├── output
│   └── htmltables.csv
└── scrapy.cfg
```

Comment: What does `scrapy list` command returns? Also could you post the source of `htmltableLoader`? As well as project directory tree?

Comment: You don't have the `propreties.py` file in your directory.

Comment: @CarlosPeña what is `propreties.py`, I generated a project with `startproject` and generated 2 spiders with `genspider`.

Comment: @ChiseledAbs that line with propreties.py looks very wrong. Most likely it was not created by scrapy when you ran the command `startproject`. Well the answer below seems correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
from googlefinance.items import htmltableitem
```

rather than

```
from propreties.items import htmltableitem
```

Looks like at first you created Scrapy project named `propreties` and then renamed directory to `googlefinance` without any other source code changes.

Replace all the entries of `propreties` in code and check `scrapy.cfg` content as well.

Comment: yeah just noticed that thanks to Carlos Pena comment I didn't know the import system worked like that I was just following a pdf.